# how do I copy a big dictionary out of the console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I do console.log(var) in chrome developer tools and it prints a bunch of keys and values into the console. I want to get those values into Excel so that I can do some analysis. How can I do that? If I right-click copy the output in the console it just copies the variable name. Is there any easy way to get that output?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(var))
```

That will output JSON array or object of your variable that has keys and values. Then you can use JSON to CSV convectors to output that for Excel